# UniqueEntity with two fields not working

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using the `UniqueEntity` constraint to ensure that I don't have two entities with the same `flowId` and `listId`.

here's my entity :

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"flowId","listId"})
 * 
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="InvitationService\Infrastructures\Persistence\Doctrine\InvitationRepository"
 * )
 * @ORM\Table(
 *     name="invitations",
 *     uniqueConstraints={
 *          @ORM\UniqueConstraint(
 *              name="flow_list_uniqueness", 
 *              columns={"flow_id", "list_id"})
 *      }
 * )
 */
 class Invitation extends Model
 {

     /**
      * @var string
      *
      * @ORM\Column(name="flow_id", type="string", length=100, nullable=false)
      */
      protected $flowId;

     /**
      * @var string
      *
      * @ORM\Column(name="list_id", type="string", length=100, nullable=false)
      */
      protected $listId;
```

When I persist a second entity with the same combination of `flowId` and `listId`, the `UniqueConstraint` with the name `flow_list_uniqueness` is triggered and I get the error :

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'flow-abc-list-abc' for key 'flow_list_uniqueness'"
```

Apparently the `UniqueEntity` doesn't do anything, I tried adding some `var_dump`s in the `UniqueEntity` class and `UniqueEntityValidator` class to make sure that these classes are at least called but I don't get any output.

I checked out some similar questions in SO and symfony's github repository, but nothing worked for me.

I'm using PHP 7.1, Symfony 3.3 and doctrine 2.5 with MySQL db.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what do you expect the UniqueEntity to do ?

Comment: I'm expecting to get an error with the default message `This value is already used.`

Comment: Did you try setting `@UniqueEntity` after the action `@ORM\Entity` ?

Comment: Also: What's the code that triggered this? If you just use `$em->persist($entity)` it's not going to do anything. Validation is triggered (for example) by `$form->isValid()` or `$errors = $validator->validate($entity);`

Comment: @ccKep : putting `@UniqueEntity` after `@ORM\Entity` doesn't do anything. 
I don't use forms nor validators, this is a backend REST API.
I wasn't aware that I need to trigger this constraint manually. I appreciate the info.

Comment: Unless you're using some bundle that does the hard work for you (eg. FOSRestBundle - never used it, but I guess it'd handle such things) you need to trigger the validation yourself. Get a validator instance (eg. in your controller `$validator = $this->get("validator");` and then use it to get possible errors: `$errors = $validator->validate($yourEntity);`.

Comment: Thank you @ccKep, I got it to work using the validator.